# Why can a variable of type Object hold a reference to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, jls

According to the [JLS, under section 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-1.html), it states that:

> A variable of class type Object can hold a null reference or a reference to any object, whether class instance or array.

This means that

```
Object obj = new Object[10];
```

is legal in Java. I understand it can be done, I want to understand if there is a proper use for this.

**Note**: I am not sure if this is a duplicate question, but I haven't found a proper answer to this on Stackoverflow, maybe I am searching with wrong keywords, it the answer already exists, do guide me there.

Answer (score 0):

be carefull that in java almost everything can be an object

so this

```
Object obj = new Object[10];
```

is as valid as

```
Object obj2 = new String("Hi");
```

or even

```
Object[] obj3 = new Object[10];
```

the main diff between obj and obj3 is that with obj3 you can do things like

```
obj[1] = "as"
```

but in obj you cant

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Object[] obj = new Object[10];
    obj[0] = new Integer(1);
    obj[1] = "hello";
    System.out.println(obj[1]);
    Object obj2 = new Object[10];
    obj2[0] = new Integer(1);
    ^--- ERROR!
}
```

I think the key is to understand how ref work, look this:

```
//CASTING
Object someString = new String("abcdf");
```

at this point someString is not a string but an object, so if you need to handle as string and use all the string methods you need to cast it to a string

```
System.out.println(((String)someString).toUpperCase());
```

trying to do

```
System.out.println(someString.toUpperCase());
```

will cause java to complain since the class "object" has no method `toUpperCase`

Comment: Why does `obj2[0] = new Integer(1);` cause an error?

Comment: becase you need to cast in order to handle that as an array

Answer (score 0):

It's possible because Object is the superclass of everything which is not a primitive datatype. As arrays are complex datatypes their superclass is Object too. So you could also write something like this

```
Object obj = new int[10];
```

But only because it's possible it doesn't mean that you should do it. With your example you're breaking typesafety in 2 ways. First, you're assigning an array to an Object and second, you're creating an array of objects. This would mean that you'd always have to cast before doing an operation on the array like setting or reading an element.
Also you'd have to cast you're array's elements back to its original type if you'd want to call any method on them. As casts can lead to ClassCastExceptions they should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand if there is a proper use for this.

There is. Sometimes it is necessary to write code where you can use a variable to refer to "any object at all". For example:

- Generic container data types. It is desirable to be able to put "any object at all" in a list or in a tree data structure, without needing to make a special version of the data structure for each type of reference. Thanks to this, you don't need a new special List interface if you want to put arrays in the list, you can just use `List<int[]>` for example.
- Reflection. It is desirable to be able to hold "any object at all" in a variable so that you can ask questions about it, questions like "what is the type of this object" or "what members does this object have". If you couldn't use the Object type to refer to arrays, you would need to write new, more specialized methods.
- The `System.arrayCopy` method. This method copies items from one array to another. The arrays are passed in using the Object type. Thanks to this, only one arrayCopy method is needed, as opposed to one for every kind of array.